# Cannot load file path for files (3D models) with Node.js Server and Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, express, three.js

I'm having difficulty loading 3D models from a folder on my computer, using a localhost node.js test server, with three.js library.

app.js: (I run it via command line in the project directory using: `node app.js` command)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var THREE = require('three');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Relevant portion of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index.html title</title>

</head>

<body>
    
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="//threejs.org/build/three.js"></script> 
<script src="//threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/AMFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="//threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script>
    
    var socket = io();
    
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    init();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x999999 ) );
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
        camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        camera.position.set( 0, -9, 6 );
        camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 ) );
        scene.add( camera );
        var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 25, 1.0, 0xffffff, 0x555555 );
        grid.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), 90 * ( Math.PI/180 ) );
        scene.add( grid );
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x999999 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
        /* everything up till here works */

        var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader(); 
        loader.load('/models/rook.amf', function ( amfobject ) { //'./models/rook.amf'

            scene.add( amfobject );
            render();

        } );

        /* ^^^ this is the part not working */

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
        controls.target.set( 0, 1.2, 2 );
        controls.update();
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    }
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        render();
    }
    function render() {    
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My project directory:

[image]

The error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/models/rook.amf 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I properly load files with Node and three.js on my simple server test?

Comment: I think you need to set up express to handle static files? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Could you please provide us a minimal reproducible example we can work on? Something like a tiny dedicated git repository. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the popular 3D formats extensions (.glb, .gltf, .fbx, .dae, .amf, ...) are not standard [MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), browsers pay a particular care when manipulating these files, attempting to safeguard the user to prevent dangerous behaviors.

So you will need to configure your web server engine to accept these extensions, otherwise you'll receive different HTTP errors downloading them. .amf is not even in this list, so **`application/octet-stream`** is the default value for all other cases. An unknown file type should use this type.

If you are using **IIS** server from an *ASP.Net* application, add the xml lines below in the **`</system.webServer>`** node of your *web.config* file:

```xml
<system.webServer>
      ...
      <staticContent>
          <remove fileExtension=".mtl" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".mtl" mimeType="model/mtl" />
          <remove fileExtension=".obj" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="model/obj" />
          <remove fileExtension=".glb" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".glb" mimeType="model/gltf-binary" />
          <remove fileExtension=".gltf" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".gltf" mimeType="model/gltf+json" />
          <remove fileExtension=".fbx" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".fbx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
          <remove fileExtension=".amf" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".amf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

If you are using an **nginx** server, add the following lines to the *nginx.conf* file in the `http` object:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    types {
        model/mtl mtl;
        model/obj obj;
        model/gltf+json gltf;
        model/gltf-binary glb;
        application/octet-stream fbx;
        application/octet-stream amf;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you are using an **Apache** server, add the following lines to the *mime.types* file:

```
model/mtl mtl
model/obj obj
model/gltf+json gltf
model/gltf-binary glb
application/octet-stream fbx
application/octet-stream amf
```

For any other web server you can surely find easily how to set the MIME Types configuration.

**EDIT:** In the case of node, review your file `server.js` is not including any restriction to these MIME types, most of the popular `server.js` scripts include limitations for non-standard MIME types

**EDIT2: I GOT IT** as I suspected it was related to the kind of MIME type AMF is. I have posted the full solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/jscastro76/ExpressThreejs)

But the important things to change are these ones below.

**First**, change your `app.js` to add the MIME type.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.use('/models', express.static('models')) // add this!
app.use('/express', express.static('express')) // add this!
express.static.mime.define({ 'application/octet-stream': ['amf'] })
//add the router
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

**Second**, because of the recent changes in Three.js (April 23), the use of AMF loader, requires of jszip module. No need to download it locally, you can consume it by url like the other js files. In my project, index.html is in a /express folder, so my path to amf model is `../models/rock.amf`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Index.html title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/AMFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script>
        var camera, scene, renderer;

        init()

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x999999));
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
            camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
            camera.position.set(0, -9, 6);
            camera.add(new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8));
            scene.add(camera);
            var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(25, 1.0, 0xffffff, 0x555555);
            grid.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
            scene.add(grid);
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor(0x999999);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            /* NOW IT WORKS!!! */

            var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader();
            loader.load('../models/rook.amf', function (amfobject) { //'./models/rook.amf'

                scene.add(amfobject);
                render();

            });

            /* ^^^ this is the part not working */

            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.addEventListener('change', render);
            controls.target.set(0, 1.2, 2);
            controls.update();
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You got it...
[image]

Comment: Hi, this looks great and I'm trying to get it to work. But using the code as-is, I cannot load my localhost:3000 (I change `port = 3000`, `baseDirectory = __dirname`). I think I am not combining my old version (`createServer(app)`) properly with your solution. How can I do this? I need the `app` stuff for express code I had before

Comment: `EDIT: In the case of node, review your file server.js is not including any restriction to these MIME types, most of the popular server.js scripts include limitations for non-standard MIME types` I have no idea how to do this. Anyways I think we're getting close, if I can get your code to work and send to display the file I'm happy to accept your answer for the bounty

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution and a link to the github repo

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it later tonight and let you know!

Comment: OK, so after being unable to modify mine to work, I literally downloaded and ran yours (after install the `npm` modules express, three). Something is up with the file path and I can't run it: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\mycomputer\Downloads\ExpressThreejs-master\ExpressThreejs-master\index.html'`. This is output of `node app.js` from command terminal running in the folder. And it's the same error I got when I modified my existing project to copy your code. So we're close but something small just missing I think!

Comment: Hey I actually got it to work! I changed one line ever so slightly to fix above comment's error: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/express/index.html'));`. Maybe because I'm on a windows machine. But THEN, what I had to do was re-download `rook.amf`, apparently the smaller file size version (maybe zipped already?) worked, while the one I had didn't. This was a very weird issue to work through, and I thank you for your help =) Bounty should come in a few hrs.

Comment: It was weird, indeed!!! And it seems the platform and the file itself had also a relationship. 
I was curious too, glad I could be of help!

Comment: @JDS This answer may have been helpful to you, but it's wrong nevertheless. `MIME-types` have nothing to do with your issue. More than that it's flooded with wrong statements about `MIME-types`, servers and browsers. Also `...as I suspected it was related to the kind of MIME type AMF` totally wrong. Look at my server's code, there is nothing about MIME and it still works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to serve the contents of the `models` folder as static files. Example:

```
app.use('/models', express.static('models'))
```

Comment: I've had a few iterations of this code and questions, and have tried that suggestion. Didn't work. I ran it again to be sure, error is `THREE.AMFLoader: Error loading AMF - no AMF document found.`

Comment: I'm creating a Node Express project to test it out and I'll be back to you

Answer (score 2):

Try to recreate these steps from **the code in the question**. And you'll succeed too. Maybe there is something else in your real code that is missing in the question. Then you should update it with this info.

1. I've copied your `app.js` and `index.html`.
2. I've loaded `rook.amf` from https://threejs.org/examples/models/amf/rook.amf and placed it in the `/models`. I suppose you did the same
3. I've added `app.use()` as others already correctly suggested.

   ```js
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()
   const http = require('http').createServer(app)
   // const io = require('socket.io')(http) // unrelated
   // const THREE = require('three') // unrelated
   app.use('/models', express.static('models')) // add this!
   app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html') })
   // io.on('connection', (socket) => console.log('a user connected')) // unrelated
   http.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on *:3000'))
   ```
4. And I've been able to download `rook.amf` with `AMFLoader`. No idea how you've managed to get the error `THREE.AMFLoader: Error loading AMF - no AMF document found.` you've mentioned in comments.
5. But then I get `THREE.AMFLoader: jszip missing and file is compressed.`
   Please note the warning in the console

   ```
   THREE.AMFLoader: As part of the transition to ES6 Modules, the files in 'examples/js' were deprecated in May 2020 (r117) and will be deleted in December 2020 (r124). You can find more information about developing using ES6 Modules in https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation.
   ```

   Maybe you should try to mimic this **updated** example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_amf.html which I, kind of, did...
6. I've downloaded `jszip.module.min.js` from the aforementioned example. And placed it in the `/models` too, just for simplicity. And added to the `index.html` as

   ```html
   <script type="module">
     import { JSZip } from "./models/jszip.module.min.js"
     window.JSZip = JSZip
   </script>
   ...
   <!-- I also had to add type="module" to the "main" script
        so it would be executed after window.JSZip = JSZip -->
   <script type="module">
     var socket = io();
     ...
   ```

   But you don't need this part if you'll use the updated version of example with `es6` modules or if you'll download `non-es6` version of `jszip`
7. Now I can see the rook on the screen!

Comment: Hey, this is also a great answer, and your post helped me realize that there was a file error in `rook.amf`, at least the version I had wasn't working.